# trying to match while excluding from front/behind - Eclipse Negative Lookahead not working as I expect it to

Tags: regex, eclipse

I am trying to write some regex to use in Eclipse file search that will find "http:", while allowing me to exclude a word or words before and after the "http:"
Before making it work for both in front and behind, I am just trying to get it to work excluding phrases in the front using negative lookahead.  So I have been trying this:

```
    ^(?!QName).*http:
```

or

```
    .*^(?!QName).*http:
```

I would expect this line to not come back in the search:

```
    // QName qn = new QName( "http://BUNDLE.wsdl","bundle");
```

But it does come back in the search.  These both match the line all the way up to http: if QName is not present, or it matches the entire line if QName is present.

Eventually I want to make it more complex where I can exclude words in the front and back:

```
    ^(?!QName|xlmns).*http:^(?!word1|word2)
```

But I am far from that point - however any help on that will be appreciated since I am likely going to have trouble with it too

Comment: Try something like`^(?!.*(?:QName|xmlns).*http:).*http:`

Comment: Thanks that did it!

Answer (score -1):

Credit to Wiktor Stribiżew in the above post

```
    ^(?!.*(?:QName|xmlns).*http:).*http:
```